# Semi-conjugacies between interval and circle maps

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

There are examples of self-maps of the circle which are semi-conjugate to self-maps of a compact interval. A famous one is the covering map $z\mapsto z^2$ of the unit circle which is semi-conjugate to the tent map, and also to the Chebyshev polynomial $[-1,1]\circlearrowleft:x\mapsto 2x^2-1$ via $z\mapsto x:=\frac{1}{2}\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)$. On the other hand, there is no semi-conjugacy between an irrational rotation and a continuous self-map of a compact interval because unlike the former, the latter must have a fixed point. So I ask the following: Is a **continuous** self-map of a circle possessing a fixed point always semi-conjugate to a **continuous** self-map of an interval? By definition, a semi-conjugacy needs to be surjective, continuous and respecting the dynamics. Here, I allow it to be in either direction but I want its fibers to be finite though.

Comment: In general, the answer is no. The reason why $z^2$ and Chebyshev polynomial have this property is that they are even. But $z^3$ already does not have this property.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko The covering $z\mapsto z^3$ is also semi-conjugate to an interval map: $z\mapsto x:=\frac{1}{2}\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)$ still works as a semi-conjugacy from the circle map onto the Chebyshev polynomial $x\mapsto 4x^3-3x$.

Comment: this is a semiconjugation in another direction. There is no semicongugation FROM the segment TO the circle. Semiconjugation is not an equivalence relation, as the name suggests. But it is easy to find an example which has no semiconjugation either way.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I have mentioned in my question that I allow semi-conjugacies in both directions.